# Defining a specific function for .getJSON

Tags: php, json, getjson

I am trying to use Json to get data from a database by calling the function.php to query the database. I am running into an issue with finding out how I specify a specific function in the function.php file to do the work.

Below is my Jquery and function.php the goal is to have Json use getlist() from function.php.

Please help I have been trying to understand this for some time now.

Jquery Function:

```
$.getJSON( "public/includes/functions.php", function( data ) {
        var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        console.log('data:' + key + ' And ' + val);
      });

     });
```

PHP Function:

```
function getlist(){

    require "dbconn.php";
    $result = $stdb->get_results("SELECT id, name FROM supplements");
    $stdb->show_errors();


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

         $array[] = $row;

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $js_array = json_encode($array);
    echo $js_array;

    mysqli_close($conn);    
}
```

Comment: You have to call the function... If you have multiple functions, you'll have to pass from the js code something for your php to read and identify which function to call...

Comment: You're not doing anything. You're just defining one function. That's it.

Comment: @FirstOne Could you point me to an article where I could learn how to pass/call the particular php function?

Comment: I don't know of any... But to make it easier, maybe you could put each in a file, then you'd make a call to the php file only (without a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON( "public/includes/functions.php?myfun=1", function( data ) {
        var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        console.log('data:' + key + ' And ' + val);
      });

     });



    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET)){
        if(isset($_GET['myfun'])){
        getlist();exit;
}
    }
    function getlist(){

        require "dbconn.php";
        $result = $stdb->get_results("SELECT id, name FROM supplements");
        $stdb->show_errors();


        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

             $array[] = $row;

            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $js_array = json_encode($array);
        echo $js_array;

        mysqli_close($conn);    
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getlist(){

    require "dbconn.php";
    $result = $stdb->get_results("SELECT id, name FROM supplements");
    $stdb->show_errors();


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

         $array[] = $row;

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $js_array = json_encode($array);
    echo $js_array;

    mysqli_close($conn);    
}
//You need to call your function
getlist();
```